# Calculate mean reciprocal rank

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way for calculating a MRR fro search engine.
I know that reciprocal rank is calculated like :

RR= 1/position of first relevant result

But this works when I know which is my query word(I mean "question")!
In my case I have only results:
.
.
.

I have following format of data available:
Correct result for query n.1:
GT=[doc1, doc2, doc3]
Result of my search engine for query n.1:
SE=[doc2,doc7,doc1]

How I should calculate the RR in this case?
Till now i'm doing it in following way:

```
 all_rr=[]
 for i in queries:
     for j in queries_results:
         pos=j.index(i[0])+1
         RR=1/pos
         all_rr.append(RR)
 MRR=np.mean(all_rr)
```

Is this a right approach?
(p.s. queries is my GT's dataframe and queries_result is my SE results dataframe)

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford flattening your results and ground truth:

```
import pandas as pd

gts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    {'query': 'q1', 'document': 'doc2'},
    {'query': 'q1', 'document': 'doc3'},
    {'query': 'q2', 'document': 'doc7'},
])

results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    {'query': 'q1', 'document': 'doc1', 'rank': 1},
    {'query': 'q1', 'document': 'doc2', 'rank': 2},
    {'query': 'q1', 'document': 'doc3', 'rank': 3},
    {'query': 'q2', 'document': 'doc4', 'rank': 1},
    {'query': 'q2', 'document': 'doc5', 'rank': 2},
    {'query': 'q2', 'document': 'doc6', 'rank': 3},
])

MAX_RANK = 100000

hits = pd.merge(gts, results,
    on=["query", "document"],
    how="left").fillna(MAX_RANK)

mrr = (1 / hits.groupby('query')['rank'].min()).mean()
```